# In JSP  <Object>tag  dll (usercontrol) not showing

Tags: c#, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a control in c# now I want to use this usercontrol in JSP I have used in < Object > tag to display that dll. it executes without exception but not displaying myControl,  just emboss that component space.

```
<OBJECT id="phoneControl" classid="phoneControl.dll#phoneControl.UserControl1" width="50%"></OBJECT>
```

Comment: I have figure out the issue it was my browser security issue I have tested my application in others PCs it works fine but I don't know what is the issue on my IE.